# Dynamic Input value empty

Tags: jquery

```
    $("#new_question").click(function() {
    $("#popup_nm").trigger("click");
    $(".modal-title").html("Soru-Yanıt Ekle");
    var pc_1 = '<form id="test" class="text-center" onsubmit="return false;">';
    var pc_2 = '<div id="div_question" class="form-group"><input id="faq_question" class="form-control" type="text" name="faq_question" placeholder="Soru" /></div>';
    var pc_3 = '<div id="div_answer" class="form-group"><textarea id="faq_answer" class="form-control" name="faq_answer" placeholder="Yanıt"></textarea></div>';
    var pc_4 = '<div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$.save_faq();">Kaydet</button></div></form>';
    $(".modal-body").html(pc_1 + pc_2 + pc_3 + pc_4); 
});

$.save_faq = function() {
    var question = $("#faq_question").val();
    console.log(question);
}
```

I have added the form dynamically, but the input values are always empty. 
I tried `$("input[name=faq_question]).val()` and it returns empty too, also I tried to serialize the form, and I get the input names but values are empty too.
How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/je81a6o9/. Check the console for errors. Note that this is on the assumption that you only allow the HTML to be appended once. If you append multiple times you will have duplicated the `id` attributes of all those elements which is invalid, and you will have to use classes to fix that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i get only one error in console : XMLHttpRequest cannot load javascript:. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-

Comment: If you're adding the HTML dynamically after the page loads, make sure the event handler is set after the HTML is added to the body and not before. If you run the event handler before the HTML is live, the handler isn't attached to anything, even if you add the HTML after.

Comment: @ÖzgünULU that's your problem then. You need to fix the AJAX request

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any errors, check the snippet (click the anchor and type something in your form then submit).

I added `$("#test").submit(function(){});` to call `$.save_faq` when you submit the form.

```js
$("#new_question").click(function() {
    var pc_1 = '<form id="test" class="text-center" onsubmit="return false;">';
    var pc_2 = '<div id="div_question" class="form-group"><input id="faq_question" class="form-control" type="text" name="faq_question" placeholder="Soru" /></div>';
    var pc_3 = '<div id="div_answer" class="form-group"><textarea id="faq_answer" class="form-control" name="faq_answer" placeholder="Yanıt"></textarea></div>';
    var pc_4 = '<div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$.save_faq();">Kaydet</button></div></form>';
    $(".modal-body").html(pc_1 + pc_2 + pc_3 + pc_4); 
});
$.save_faq = function() {
    var question = $("#faq_question").val();
    console.log(question);
}
$("#test").submit(function(){
  $.save_faq();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id = "new_question">click</a>
<div class = "modal-body"></div>
```